# append boost to codeblocks : undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'|

Tags: c++, boost, codeblocks

I'm trying to compile a program on windows with codeblocks using Boost libraries. Even I set compiler and linker, it compiles fail:

```
 undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

I use the same config with codelite and it compile an run well, but codelite often crashs so I change to codeblock and get this error

Comment: Try omitting the `lib` prefix on any dlls you're including to pass to the linker phase.

Comment: Just FYI you do realize that visual studio 2015 community is a full-fledged version of visual studio that's free for personal use and open source projects, right?